# How to align two elements at the same vertical position

Tags: html, css

I have the following case:

[image]

but I would like that everytime and beta are displayed at the same vertical position as this:

[image]

I have the following html:

```
<h1 style="display: block;margin: 0 auto;position: relative;">
    <svg enable-background="new 0 0 298.9 55.8" viewBox="0 0 298.9 55.8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <style type="text/css">.st0{fill:#231F20;}</style>
        <path class="st0" d="..."></path>
    </svg>
    <p style="position: absolute;left: 85%;font-size: 50%;color: white;line-height: 0px;">beta</p>
</h1>
```

How can I solve this issue? Keep in mind that everytime should be centered, and beta should be to the right of it.

Comment: Why are you doing inline styles first off, but to get the job done, can you post your CSS...

Comment: @TGarret, I have almost no experience with CSS, so I just was following what I found in a tutorial, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[position: fixed](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

```
position: fixed;left: 85%
```

Comment: it didn't work, what happened was that the element was pushed a little bit more to the right.

Comment: play with where it is located. `left: 60%; top: 10%;` until it is where you want it.

Comment: it worked, but how can I handle this situation because it should be responsive for mobile devices.

Comment: Can you create 2 different logos, one with beta and one without, and show which one you want depending on whether they are beta or not? Then you can put it wherever you want and you wouldn't have to worry about the position or responsiveness.

Comment: I would prefer not to create two logos, so that is why I am asking this question, but so far your answer seems the best I have gotten.

Comment: If you get the positioning and sizing correct, the fixed position should still work on mobile because fixed is relative to the viewport.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141913/discussion-between-lmiguelvargasf-and-austin-winstanley).

Answer (score 0):

```
<p style="position:absolute; left:85%; font-size: 50%;color:#333; line-height: 0px; vertical-align: middle; display:inline-block; ">beta</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head> 
<style>
.vasile
{
display: inline-block;
line-height: 1px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
</style></head>
<body>
<div>
<h1 class="vasile"> asdasda</h1>
<p class="vasile">asdasda</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```